# ngx-chips, when disable attribute is set to false the tag-input-dropdown displays

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

When using ngx-chips I have a button that is disabling the input. When the input is enabled the tag-input-dropdown displays as if the user has clicked on the input field.

Here is a working demo of this issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-chip-dropdown-test)

I have tried using an ngIf on the *tag-input-dropdown* linked to the disable variable, although this fixes my specific issue it breaks the search functionality.

I have added a bug report to the ngx-chips [github page](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/872) but as it could take a while for this to get looked at, does anyone have any suggestions of a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a reply on the [ngx-chips GitHub page](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/872) about adding [keepOpen]="false" to my tag-input-dropdown and this fixes the issue with disabling the field.

```
<tag-input-dropdown
    [appendToBody]="true"
    [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true"
    [keepOpen]="false"
    [autocompleteItems]="tagItems"
    [identifyBy]="'id'"
    [displayBy]="'title'">
</tag-input-dropdown>
```